# selenide + cucumber как сохранить глобальную информацию

Tags: test-automation, cucumber, selenide

Насколько я понимаю, selenide пропагандирует процедурный подход со статическими вызовами методов. По ходу выполнения тестов хотелось бы иметь под рукой часть параметров сеанса, как лучше это реализовать?

При этом часть параметров известна заранее, часть может изменяться по ходу теста. Я бы хотел, например, создать отдельный класс, в экземпляр которого записывать необходимые параметры. Но тогда я не смогу обращаться к экземпляру на чтение/запись из статического контекста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запись параметров в статические поля отдельного класса решает проблему